# How to get campaign owner from campaign member

Tags: apex, trigger, campaign, campaign-member

```
trigger SendEmailOnDeleteCampaignMember on CampaignMember (after delete) {

    CampaignMember cmp = trigger.old[0];
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    email.setToAddresses(new String[] {cmp.Email,cmp.CampaignId.OwnerId.email});
    email.setSubject('Deleted campaign member Alert');
    email.setPlainTextBody('This message is to alert you that the campaign member named ' + cmp.LastName + ' has been deleted.');
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});   
}
```

I'm getting error like ownerid does not exist.
Help me with this
thanks in advance.

Comment: `email.setToAddresses(new String[] {cmp.Email,cmp.CampaignId.OwnerId.email});` instead of `CampaignId.OwnerId.email` use `Campaign.Owner.email`

Comment: Hi @Tushar I tried using `Campaign.Owner.email` but I'm getting null value instead of email address

Comment: @user55164 Read the Note section in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are syntax error in your code. Instead of this `cmp.CampaignId.OwnerId.email` you need to do this `cmp.Campaign.Owner.email` to get the owner email address. You can also use `cmp.Campaign.OwnerId` to send the email address. As it will be counted internal email and not be counted towards limits.

**Note:** As you are in trigger so you can't access parent field directly. You need to first query the fields and then you can use them.

Answer (score -1):

As per the above mentioned comment try to change the `CampaignId.OwnerId.email` to `Campaign.Owner.email`